# Align left items in table but at the center

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

here is a simple table, with a fixed width :

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tokyo-Yokohama</td>
      <td>37,843,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jakarta</td>
      <td>30,539,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
      <td>24,998,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Manila</td>
      <td>24,123,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I align items between them to their left side but with the largest (Tokyo-Yokohama) at the center, like on this picture:

[image]

I'm looking for a solution without having to specify a fixed padding-left on other items, and it should work whatever the width of the table is.

Here is an exemple of the beahvior I'm looking for, but with a cleaner html : https://codepen.io/ired4321/pen/abJrYWY?editors=1100

Comment: You can't. The example you linked to is not a real table, or better said: It *is*  a table, but in that table there is only *one* row which contains three cells. These cells contain `div`s that have `display: flex`, and which form "fake columns". Semantically this is a table with only one row, as I wrote, so for example for a screen reader or for SEO it won't properly work as a table. And as soon as the contents of any table cell needs to break into a second line, the row layout (i.e. the border lines) breaks (try it).

Comment: Yes I i know, i did this exemple myself. I will fix the break to a second line by using an ellipsis and put '...' at the end. I don't care about screen readers or sao, it just need to look like a table for an end user, with cliquable row. Please take a look at the exemple, i've updated it, it's cleaner. Actually, my only need now is to make it cliquable with a href or something but idk how without javascrit... Maybe I really need javascript now

Comment: To "make it clickable" you can simply put a link tag (`<a>...</a>`) around each to-be-clickable element, and adjust the styling for the different `a` tags inside that "table" using combined CSS selectors and settings like `text-decoration: none` , `color: [same as your regular text]` etc.

Comment: yes this is what i can do but it will be better if i don't have to reapeat the same link for each cell of a row, it create a bigger html file with bigger bandwith use... idk what I'll do

Comment: a few THML tags nowadays certainly don't count for bandwidth - complex javascripts and *huge* stylesheets do, but not this.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `td` a padding to give a little space at the edge and so `Tokyo-Yokohama` is in the middle but the rest on the left side. You can remove the borders. I added them just to show the example

Here's the code:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0 0; /* to reduce border spaces */
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="center">Tokyo-Yokohama</td>
      <td>37,843,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jakarta</td>
      <td>30,539,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
      <td>24,998,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Manila</td>
      <td>24,123,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes but this isn't working in all situations, here you are choosing this padding to make it work with Tokyo-Yokohama. But I have  fields comming from a database and it can be any length. And the table could be any length too and Tokyo-Yokohama shoud still be at the center

Comment: @LéoParent i updated my Answer. Does it work now for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `padding-left` and `padding-right` to mimic the same effect you have in the photo like this

```css
td {
    padding-left: 5vw;
    padding-right: 5vw;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tokyo-Yokohama</td>
      <td>37,843,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jakarta</td>
      <td>30,539,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
      <td>24,998,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Manila</td>
      <td>24,123,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** instead of having a fixed pixel value you could use `vw` instead and have it control by a percentage relative to 1% of the width of the viewport, however i would recommend to have it as my previous answer in `px` padding can be a fixed value as it won't be effected by the table size.

Comment: Yes but this isn't working in all situations, here 30px is choosed. And other columns could need other values than 30px to make the largest beat the center. And when the table is resized, it's broken

Comment: @LéoParent i have just updated my code, please note that the table size can be changed and that won't have any effects on the padding

Comment: Thank you this is much better but not perfect. But it's my bad it's working in the exemple I choosed. But my real data is coming from databases and could be any length. And setting the right vw value for left and right padding to center data for each column isn't very possible in this case...

Comment: hi @LéoParent if my answer helped you check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers